# Can i tag elements in excel (or other program) to find them by searching the tag?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, tags

I apologise in advance for the probably stupid question with an easy solution. I play in a band on a live tv show and im lookin for a fast way to find the songs I need to play in a long list by searching keywords that i will asociate with the songs. Let me give you an example.

Lets say the director tells us "play something sad that involves women". From that point we have 10 seconds to decide at best. So i wanna write all the songs in a list and tag them. "Sad", "happy","angry" and so on. So i search for "sad","women" and it displays "no woman no cry A major" and all the other related songs, for example.

Thank you.

Comment: Hmm. That is built into iTunes. I use the Comments field for things like that.

Answer (score 1):

If the songs are in iTunes, you can add ‘tags’ by typing your tags into the song's Comments field. Select the song or songs you'd like to set the tags on, then right-click and choose Get Info or press ⌘I, and type your tags into the Comments. You can use iTunes search to find these songs again by the tags you entered.